# String Split sql function only returning first word in string

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I have a function:

```sql
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[func_ParseString] (@list nvarchar(MAX))
   RETURNS @tbl TABLE (string VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL) AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @pos        int,
           @nextpos    int,
           @valuelen   int

   SELECT @pos = 0, @nextpos = 1

   WHILE @nextpos > 0
   BEGIN
      SELECT @nextpos = charindex(', ', @list, @pos + 1)
      SELECT @valuelen = CASE WHEN @nextpos > 0
                              THEN @nextpos
                              ELSE len(@list) + 1
                         END - @pos - 1
      INSERT @tbl (string)
         VALUES (substring(@list, @pos + 1, @valuelen))
      SELECT @pos = @nextpos
   END
  RETURN
END
```

I have a table

| id | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Dan | 20 |
| 2 | Chris | 30 |
| 3 | Andy | 20 |

When I try a select in statement it only returns all values for the first name in my comma delimited string

```sql
SELECT * FROM table  
WHERE name IN (SELECT string COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT FROM [dbo].[func_ParseString]('Dan, Andy')
```

This only returns row 1 when I want to return rows 1 and 3

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is returning a leading blank in front of Andy.

You should use `LTRIM` function to remove it. Either in function, on insert into @tbl:

```
 INSERT @tbl (string)
         VALUES (LTRIM (substring(@list, @pos + 1, @valuelen)))
```

or when you call function:

```
SELECT LTRIM(string) FROM [dbo].[func_ParseString] ('Dan, Andy')
```

Comment: that worked  for me, I used it when I called the function and so used the second option you gave, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember where I found this function. I implemented it and works nice

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[StringSplit]
(
  @delimited nvarchar(max),
  @delimiter nvarchar(100)
) RETURNS @t TABLE
(
-- Id column can be commented out, not required for sql splitting string
  id int identity(1,1), -- I use this column for numbering splitted parts
  val nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
  declare @xml xml
  set @xml = N'<root><r>' + replace(@delimited,@delimiter,'</r><r>') + '</r></root>'

  insert into @t(val)
  select 
    r.value('.','varchar(max)') as item
  from @xml.nodes('//root/r') as records(r)

  RETURN
END

GO

DECLARE @String NVARCHAR(max)
SET @String = 'Dan, Andy'

SELECT Val FROM [dbo].[StringSplit] (@String, ',')
```

Answer (score 0):

STRING_SPLIT is available in SQL server 2016.