# Dealing with splitting strings in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently I'm working on a project where we just added the ability to have multiple values stored within a field.  Previously, it stored a single value, but now it contains multiple.  Below is an example of what I'm talking about.

Ex.  A person's name is passed in (John Smith).  Now the user can pass in multiple people's names, delimited by a ';' (John Smith;John Doe;Jane Tandy).

My issue is that we have a data source for a drop down that currently feeds off this field.  Below is the SQL for it.

```
Select Distinct Content
From LIB_DocumentAttribute A
   inner join LIB_PublicDocument B on A.PublicDocumentId = B.PublicDocumentId 
Where AttributeId = (Select AttributeId From LIB_Attribute Where FieldName='Author')
   and B.Status = 'Approved'
```

This somewhat works now.  Content is the field that contains the multiple names.  Now when the drop down is loaded, it pulls back the concatenated string of names (the longer one from above).  I want to break it apart for the data source.  So far, my only ideas is to split out the data based on the ';'.  However, I need to take that split out data and apply it to the table that returns the rest of the data.  Below is where I have gotten to but have become stuck on.

```
CREATE TABLE #Authors
(
    Content varchar(MAX)
)
CREATE TABLE #Temp1
(
    Content varchar(MAX)
)
CREATE TABLE #Temp2
(
    Content varchar(MAX)
)
CREATE TABLE #Temp3
(
    Content varchar(MAX)
)

--Load Authors table to store all Authors
INSERT INTO #Authors
Select Distinct Content
    From LIB_DocumentAttribute A
        inner join LIB_PublicDocument B on A.PublicDocumentId = B.PublicDocumentId 
    Where AttributeId = (Select AttributeId From LIB_Attribute Where FieldName='Author')
        and B.Status = 'Approved'

--Take multiple Authors separated by '; ' and add to Temp1
INSERT INTO #Temp1
SELECT REPLACE(Content, '; ', ';') FROM #Authors WHERE Content LIKE '%; %'

--Remove multiple Authors separated by '; ' from Authors table
DELETE FROM #Authors
WHERE Content LIKE '%; %'

--Take multiple Authors separated by ';' and add to Temp2
INSERT INTO #Temp2
SELECT Content FROM #Authors WHERE Content LIKE '%;%'

--Remove multiple Authors separated by ';' from Authors table
DELETE FROM #Authors
WHERE Content LIKE '%;%'

--Somewhow split data and merge back together

DROP TABLE #Authors
DROP TABLE #Temp1
DROP TABLE #Temp2
DROP TABLE #Temp3
```

Edit:

So in the end, I came up with a solution that utilized some of the pieces that Kumar suggested.  I created a function for splitting the string as he suggested and added some personal changes to make it work.  Mind you this is in a table return function, with the table called @Authors, and it has one column called Content.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @Temp TABLE
(
    Content varchar(MAX)
)

--Load Authors table to store all Authors
INSERT INTO @Authors
    Select Distinct Content
    From LIB_DocumentAttribute A
        inner join LIB_PublicDocument B on A.PublicDocumentId = B.PublicDocumentId 
    Where AttributeId = (Select AttributeId From LIB_Attribute Where FieldName='Author')

--Take multiple Authors separated by ', ' and add to Temp
INSERT INTO @Temp
        SELECT REPLACE(Content, ', ', ',')
        FROM @Authors;

    --Remove multiple Authors separated by ', ' from Authors table
    DELETE FROM @Authors
    WHERE Content LIKE '%,%';


    --Readd multiple Authors now separated into Authors table
    INSERT INTO @Authors
        SELECT s.Content
        FROM @Temp
            OUTER APPLY SplitString(Content,',') AS s
        WHERE s.Content <> (SELECT TOP 1 a.Content FROM @Authors a WHERE s.Content = a.Content)

    RETURN
END
```

Comment: This function might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543934/string-split-sql-function-only-returning-first-word-in-string?rq=1

Comment: FYI, if you **ever** want to search on a single value within this new field, you are better off creating a link table that stores one value per row.  If you don't do it now, you'll wish you did later when your queries become slow and cumbersome to create.  With that said, you can create a stored procedure that will loop the field and parse the string (exactly why it becomes a slow process, especially during batch operations when you're working with more than one row in a set).

Comment: @ps2goat The only reason that was not done was that the original table was designed for dynamic elements.  We have several fields stored within the table and thus keep them lumped together in an effort to keep things simpler.  Myself, I would have done something similar too, but it is what it is at this point.

Comment: @KristyWelsh That didn't exactly help.  Thanks though.

Comment: I suggest that you split out the names in the application code that creates the dropdown.  You may also consider changing your delimeter to something that is guaranteed to not appear in a name, chr(30) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the demo in fiddler link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/390f8/11

```
Create table test(name varchar(1000));

    Insert into test values('AAA BBB; CCC DDD; eee fff');
    CREATE FUNCTION SplitString
    (    
          @Input NVARCHAR(MAX),
          @Character CHAR(1)
    )
    RETURNS @Output TABLE (
          Item NVARCHAR(1000)
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
          DECLARE @StartIndex INT, @EndIndex INT

          SET @StartIndex = 1
          IF SUBSTRING(@Input, LEN(@Input) - 1, LEN(@Input)) <> @Character
          BEGIN
                SET @Input = @Input + @Character
          END

          WHILE CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input) > 0
          BEGIN
                SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input)

                INSERT INTO @Output(Item)
                SELECT SUBSTRING(@Input, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1)

                SET @Input = SUBSTRING(@Input, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@Input))
          END

          RETURN
    END



Declare @name varchar(100)
Declare @table as table(name varchar(1000))
Declare cur cursor for
Select name from test

Open cur
fetch next from cur into @name
while (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin
Insert into @table
   Select * from dbo.splitstring(@name,';')
    fetch next from cur into @name
end
close cur
deallocate cur


Select * from @table
```

Comment: This is definitely a step in the direction I need to go.  The only issue is I need it to work for multiple rows.  If possible, could you rework it to do that?  Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  You gave me pretty good direction in which way to go, so I'm giving you credit.  My solution isn't exactly the same, but again, you gave me more than enough ideas to get one done.  Thanks once more.

Answer (score 1):

this might work.

```
drop table authors
GO
create table Authors (Author_ID int identity (1,1),name varchar (255), category varchar(255))
GO
insert into authors
(name,category)
select 
'jane doe','nonfiction'
union 
select
'Jules Verne; Mark Twain; O. Henry', 'fiction'
union 
select 
'John Smith; John Doe', 'nonfiction'
GO
DECLARE @table TABLE (
names VARCHAR(255)
,id INT
)
DECLARE @category VARCHAR(255)

SET @category = 'nonfiction'

DECLARE @Author_ID INT

DECLARE AuthorLookup CURSOR
FOR
SELECT Author_ID
FROM authors
WHERE category = @category

OPEN AuthorLookup

FETCH NEXT
FROM AuthorLookup
INTO @Author_ID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
IF (
        SELECT CHARINDEX(';', NAME, 0)
        FROM authors
        WHERE Author_ID = @Author_ID
        ) = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @table
    SELECT NAME
        ,Author_ID
    FROM authors
    WHERE Author_ID = @Author_ID
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    DECLARE @value VARCHAR(255)

    SELECT @value = NAME
    FROM authors
    WHERE Author_ID = @Author_ID

    WHILE len(@value) > 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @table
        SELECT substring(@value, 0, CHARINDEX(';', @value, 0))
            ,@Author_ID

        SELECT @value = replace(@value, substring(@value, 0, CHARINDEX(';', @value, 0) + 2), '')

        IF CHARINDEX(';', @value, 0) = 0
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @table
            SELECT @value
                ,@Author_ID

            SET @value = ''
        END
    END
END

FETCH NEXT
FROM AuthorLookup
INTO @Author_ID
END

CLOSE AuthorLookup

DEALLOCATE AuthorLookup

SELECT *
FROM @table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create function to split your data

```
create function SplitString
(    
   @data nvarchar(max),
   @sep char(1)
)
returns @result table (data nvarchar(max))
as
begin
  declare @i int

  while 1 = 1
  begin
    select @i = charindex(@sep, @data)

    if @i = 0
    begin
      insert into @result
      select @data

      break
    end

    insert into @result
    select rtrim(left(@data, @i - 1))

    select @data = ltrim(right(@data, len(@data) - @i))
  end

  return
end
```

and use it like this:

```
select s.data
from test as t
    outer apply SplitString(t.data,';') as s
```

If you're sure that you don't have special characters inside your data, you can also consider trick with xml:

```
;with cte as (
    select
        cast('<s>' + replace(data, ';', '</s><s>') + '</s>' as xml) as data
    from test
)
select
    t.c.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as data
from cte
    outer apply data.nodes('s') as t(c)
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9cde1/5)</kbd>**